# popup windows, popwin problem?

Tags: window

I recently started using spacemacs/emacs, and encountered the following problem:

When I enable `popwin-mode` I would expect popup windows to get handled by `popwin`. However, when I run occur (`M-x occur`), it seems to not be - the buffer with the occur results always gets opened in another buffer either to the left or right of the current one. And can not be closed with `C-g`, as advertised.

Having set `popwin-window-position` to bottom, I would also expect occur to open a new buffer below the current one. But, as I said, it does not.

Could anyone help me fix whatever is the problem here?

Comment: What is the value of the option `popwin:special-display-config`? The default value of `popwin:special-display-config` has an entry `(occur-mode :noselect t)` which should handle `occur-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tobias's comment led me to the solution.

`popwin` has a variable `special-display-config` which specifies, in various ways, on what buffers it should act on. The spacemacs default configuration does not by default handle `occur-mode`. I added an entry named `*occur*` via `M-x customize-variable`, and now it works.