# How to exit org-agenda windows without deleting existing windows?

Tags: org-agenda

I am trying to use [popwin](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/popwin) to make org-agenda related windows popup windows. My goal is to dismiss agenda windows with `C-g` when done, leaving the whole window configuration the same way as it was before the agenda windows showed up.

(Dismissing agenda windows with `q` seems to delete some of the existing windows that they replace.)

I've installed popwin via MELPA and tried to set the related variable in `init.el` as described in the documentation:

```
(require 'popwin)
(push '(org-agenda-mode :position bottom) popwin:special-display-config)
(popwin-mode 1)
```

However, this does not seem to work. Pressing `C-g` doesn't dismiss the agenda window (which is launched with `C-c a t` and then `t`). I've also tried using `agenda-mode` instead of `org-agenda-mode` in above without success. Yet, popwin and `C-g` works on occur-mode, and the customization show up in `M-x customize-variable` interface.

(This is with Emacs 27.1 installed via PPA under Ubuntu 20.04)

My question is:

*How to correctly set up emacs so that existing windows are preserved after closing org agenda windows?*

Related:

[popup windows, popwin problem?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28335)

[How to control in which window a buffer is displayed?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/721) (solution doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite by chance, I encountered [this blog](https://sainathadapa.github.io/emacs-spacemacs-config/org-config), which has the following setting from org-mode itself that does exactly what I need:

> Restore layout after exit from agenda view
>
> (setq org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit t)

After adding this to `init.el`, hitting `q` on transitional org agenda windows no longer deletes the windows that they replace.